# Error on my html because of type MIME

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

So I have a problem with my project, I have develop a node js server and now I would like to display a html file that contains a Vue script which load a data thanks to another method written in another JS file.

But when I try to load my html file on my browser, I have this error : Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/src/verbatims.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

       <script src="/src/verbatims.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>


        <title>My project</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="data">
            Le nombre de requête est de  : {{ request }}<br>
            <button v-on:click="change">Change value</button>
            <button v-on:click="stop">Arrêter</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            let app = new Vue({
                el:'#data',
                data: {
                    request: "toto",
                    ite: 0
                },
                methods: {
                    change: function() {
                        changeNbRequest()
                    },
                    stop: function() {
                        clearInterval()
                    }
                }
            });

            changeNbRequest = function() {
                var timer = setInterval(function() {
                    let verbatim = new Verbatims().list()[ite];
                }, 5000);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have check every type MIME in my project but nothing is working.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Edit : here is my server code :

```
const express = require('express')
const RouterVerbatim = require('./routerVerbatim')
const fs = require('fs')

class Server {

  constructor() {
    this.app = express()

    this.app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello World')
    })

    this.app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/View/index.html', function (err,data) {
          res.end(data);
      });
    })

    this.app.get('../src/verbatims.js', function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
      fs.readFile('../src/verbatims.js', function (err,data) {
          res.end(data);
      });
    })

    this.app.use('/verbatims', new RouterVerbatim().router)
  }

  start() {
    this.app.listen(8080, function() {
      console.log('Exemple app listening on port 8080!')
    })
  }

}
module.exports = Server;
```

Comment: We can't tell why your web server is claiming that `/src/verbatims.js` is an HTML document based on the information you've provided.

Comment: It is likely a 404 html error page - try `<script src="src/verbatims.js" type="application/javascript"></script>` instead of `/src` - also you likely want to load the vue.js before any other js file

Comment: @Quentin What do you need?

Comment: @mplungjan I trythis way but I steel have the same error

Comment: @MissKnacki — Enough details to determine how the server decides what response it is going to make.

Comment: @Quentin check the edit, is it enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> '../src/verbatims.js'
> ```

The browser is never going to send a request with `../` in the URL.

It will normalise the path before sending.

You need to specify the route as `/src/verbatims.js`.

---

You should also look at using a static file handling middleware rather than manually creating a route for each one.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I have normalised the path and it works !

Comment: I already try to use a static file handling middleware but it didn't work :/